# What settings should be used on stacked guitar delays to get slow attack and infinite sustain notes?

Tags: effects-pedal

What settings should be used on up to three standard (for example, BOSS DD-3) stacked guitar delays to get slow attack and infinite sustain notes? I know that this can be done but I'm looking for some sort of formula to calculate the times, feedback, and wet/dry mix.

Comment: Are you asking about volume swells? Like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l9uX_slwbzk

Answer (score 3):

I find the best way to get a slow attack is not in the delay, but using the volume knob or a volume pedal or dynamic technique. That said, any wet/dry mix over 50% wet will mean the delay sound is louder than the dry sound, which can help give a slow attack.

Infinite sustain is simply 100% feedback (or higher). I would try 75% wet and feedback all the way up and see what you get, and adjust to taste. With those settings, delay time controls attack time and also how ringy or metallic it sounds. Very short times will sound slightly like a flanger in a way. A very long delay time will sound more like a looper, which is probably not what you want.

In practice, I do not like truly infinite sustain. Instead I like feedback at 98%-99% so that the sound does eventually die away. Another option is to have a delay where you can control the feedback with a pedal, so you can dial it up and back like the sustain pedal on a piano.

Also note that analog delays that use BBDs don’t copy the signal perfectly and you get generation losses each time it feeds back. Often this is a really cool sound where the tone slowly degrades into muted noise, but it may not be what you want.

Also you don’t need three stacked delays or formulas. It’s not nearly that complicated.

Answer (score 2):

As Todd and Tim have mentioned, delay is not the best tool for the job.

A simple setup I have used is an envelope modifier to slow the attack, and then a sustainer to hold the note as long as you want.

2 pedals, really simple to set up.

Comment: I did not recommend against using delay. I've used delay for slow attack and infinite sustain on stage many times myself - I just recommend using the volume knob for the attack.

Comment: Apologies for misunderstanding Todd

Answer (score 1):

A delay pedal would work, but it's not the right tool for the job.

Try a 'Freeze' pedal, designed to do just that. Leaving the delay pedal to do what *it* was designed for.

Add to this an inexpensive volume pedal, problem solved.